# Separate the classes for each responsibility?

Tags: object-oriented, php, class-design

I like to know what the advantages to putting the logic in separate classes rather than putting all the logic in the `RuleManager` class.

For example

Separate the classes for each responsibility

```
class RuleManager {

    public function create(string $name)
    {
        return (new CreateRuleCommand($name));
    }


    public function list()
    {
        return new ListRulesCommand();
    }

}
```

vs:

```
class RuleManager {

    public function create(string $name)
    {
        // Do all the create logic Here

        return $something
    }


    public function list()
    {
        // Add all the listing Logic Here

        return $something
    }

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate a bit.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends entirely on what the "create logic" is. After all, these could represent exactly the same code.

Your code example not withstanding, separating concerns allows a single responsibility to live in only one place. The advantage you get from that is localized change.  Boss wants ListRulesCommand to allow custom sorting it's really nice if you don't end up needing to change 5 `list()` methods in 5 different classes.

But you say you don't have 5 classes, just the 1? In that case your classes had damn well make the code easier to read.  Otherwise the advantage is not much at all. Only thing you did was reduce the chances some goof will copy your one class and duplicate your code without refactoring out the duplication.  You can drive yourself mad trying to defend against that.